# How to listen for the successful setting of a video wallpaper in Android Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

I'm working on setting a video wallpaper for Android, but I can't determine when it's successfully installed.

I tried to set broadcast receiver to listen service, but I cant know how to set Broadcast.
This is a funtion of my service (extend from WallpaperService) to set video wallpaper

```
fun setToWallPaper(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER)
            val component = ComponentName(context, VideoLiveWallpaperService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, component)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(intent)

            try {
                WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).clear()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```